# Show fourier series approximations are bounded by norms.

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series, interpolation

I am trying to find a proof on Fourier series approximation.

Comment: What is $H_p^s$ again? (I don't follow what you said because I'd expect "the standard $L^2$ Sobolev space" to be indexed by one parameter, not two. What are $s$ and $p$? Maybe you meant $H_2^s$?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks for your help. I have updated the question with more details...

Comment: By the definition you gave, $H_2^s=H_4^s=H_\pi^s$. Surely you actually meant $H_2^s$, as I suspected.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes. I think you're right. I have been trying to read up on this all weekend to get this proof and I am really at a loss. :(

Comment: So far I have:

$$\|f-f_N\|_{H_p^j} \leq \sum_{r=0}^j\|f^{(r)}\|_{L^2}^2-\sum_{|j=0|}\hat{f}_j(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ijx}$$

$$\leq \sum_{r=0}^j \int_0^{2\pi}|f^{(r)}(x)|\,dx-\sum_{|j=0|} \hat{f}_j(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ijx}$$

I just don't know what to do next. I know how to show that $\|f-f_N\|_{L^2}\leq
N^{-s} \|f\|_{H_p^s}$. But I can't tell if that relates to this or not because of the different norm.

Comment: Being more careful with notation would be good: Your $\hat f_j(x)$ doesn't make much sense, should be $\hat f(j)$. Anyway, have you tried to apply Parseval here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68987/discussion-between-math4life-and-david-c-ullrich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true for $j>s$; if $j\le s$ it's immediate from the expression of the $H_2^s$ norm in terms of Fourier coefficients.

Of various equivalent forms we take $$||f||_s^2=\sum_n(1+|n|)^{2s}|\hat f(n)|^2.$$ If $j\le s$ and $|n|>N$ then $(1+|n|)^j=(1+|n|)^s(1+|n|)^{(j-s)}
\le N^{j-s}(1+|n|)^s$. So $$||f-f_N||_j^2=\sum_{|n|>N}(1+|n|)^{2j}|\hat f(n)|^2\le N^{2(j-s)}\sum_{|n|>N}(1+|n|)^{2s}|\hat f(n)|^2
\le N^{2(j-s)}||f||_s^2.$$

Comment: We have that $j\leq s$. I would be so grateful if you could show me how it is done. I am really at a complete loss. This is my first time seeing this sort of proof.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to go through this.